# force url interpreation with urlrewriting

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, apache2

On my wiki I would like redirect all queries (for example http://mywikiofme.com/images/... ) to a php script script.php

**I put this in my virtual host :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /script.php?url=$1
```

But it doesn't work if the folder already exist on the server...

**If I test :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foldernotexist/(.*)$ /script.php?url=$1
```

The redirection to script.php works fine.

I think I need to use a flag but I don't know which one.

Ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically - should work =)

```
<Directory "/htdocs/images">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /images/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /script.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

Where ***"/htdocs/images"*** is your path to images folder

Comment: No, my picture is always loaded (instead of my script) :(

Comment: @Paul do you use **NGINX**?
Or **ModRewrite** rules in  **.htaccess**?

Comment: sure: http://pastebin.com/E8L5qXk8 this config works but with images2 folder instead of images folder.